# Error uploading CiviCRM contacts. Can I revert?

Tags: contacts, import

Does anyone know how I can revert a contact import (via the upload contacts script included in the site). The process included merges with existing contacts.

Comment: Did you back up your database before clicking "Import"?

Comment: Yes, I was just curious if there was a way inside the actual civicrm interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To revert an import done with the import functionality at **Contacts > Import Contacts**, you will need to restore from your backed up database file. As far as I know, there is no automatic "undo" on imports.

To your point, it might be worthwhile to add a new warning to the import "Are you sure" verification message that pops up right before the import fires:
[image: Import warning]

For example, "Are you sure you want to import now? Be sure you have backed up your database as there is no 'undo' for this." *(Update: [I submitted a patch](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16778) so if the core team agrees this will be added in future versions)*

Comment: Complete answer and then some. Luckily, I regularly backup my database but was hoping there was a quicker fix.

Answer (score 1):

Note that if you have advanced logging turned on, there's an option to revert - though changing an import would require you know the names of all the tables touched by the import.  See [the script on this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/35435/12) for doing the reversion.

The tables you'd revert would always include `civicrm_contact`, but also potentially `civicrm_address`, `civicrm_email`, `civicrm_phone`, `civicrm_website`, `civicrm_im`, and `civicrm_relationship`.  Fortunately there's no real harm in specifying tables that weren't touched.