# How can I revert a set of bulk changes to the database?

Tags: import, logging

I made a bulk update of addresses that turned out to be incorrect.  I have advanced logging enabled.  I can go into each contact's change log and revert the mistake one by one; how can I do this for all the addresses I altered?

Answer (score 6):

I was able to create a script to revert in bulk.  I needed to look up the `log_conn_id` value associated with the bulk change I made.  I made the change using the API import, but any change that happens in a single connection can be reverted.  Simply change the value of `$log_conn_id` in the script below, and change `$tablesToRevert` to include the table(s) that need reversion.

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
eval(`cv php:boot`);

$log_conn_id = '5dcf086e9a837';
$log_date = NULL;
$tablesToRevert = ['civicrm_address'];

$reverter = new CRM_Logging_Reverter($log_conn_id, $log_date);
$differ = new CRM_Logging_Differ($log_conn_id, $log_date);
$diffs = $differ->diffsInTables($tablesToRevert);
$reverter->setDiffs($diffs);
$reverter->revert();
```